# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. UNION CTE

Tags: sql-server

I've been given a view to troubleshoot.  It begins with a CTE that gets all values of a surrogate key used in several tables with UNIONs between each query. It then uses this CTE as an INNER JOIN to select data about those surrogate keys. The query is like the following code:

```
WITH emp AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeSk FROM view1
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeSK FROM Table1
    UNION
    --then there are two views that if you include BOTH, the overall query fails
    SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeSK FROM view2
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeSK FROM View3 )
SELECT Col1, col2, col3
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN emp
    ON t2.EmployeeSK = emp.EmployeeSK
```

Whenever you use the CTE, users get the error:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

If you select each query separately all are returning INTs.  In fact, I double checked each query by running the following query against each source:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(<tableSK>, 'BaseType') FROM <source Table or view>
```

All queries report that all columns returned are INT.

I have also created a #tempTable:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp ( SurrogateKey INT)
```

Then inserted each query into the #tempTable and all inserts work. All values are INTs.  The values range from -1 to 16435.

I can get all the queries to work with the UNION as long as I return one of two of the queries.  If I remove either of these queries the CTE and UNION statements will work, but I cannot use both.  The values for these two queries are also INTs and have values from -1 to 16435 too.

I'm at a loss as to why I get this error. Other than re-writing the view to be a stored procedure, and putting the values into a temp table, what could I try?

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you provided the failing code and some sample data that makes it fail.

Comment: I can provide the basic code, but the data to break it is the problem.  Like I mentioned if I select each of the values one table or view at a time, there is no error.  The UNION itself especially when more than one of two queries is used that is creating the error.

Comment: The queries that are part of the union and data types for the columns should be enough.

Comment: Also, the definition for the EmployeeSKs are are INT.  IF you use the SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY query above it confirms the datatypes for all views are INT.

Comment: I ran into this situation.  I fixed it by using `cast([field] as int)` for the offending fields.